# Does ffprobe support multiple "outputs"

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

If I were to want to encode a video to two different output with ffmpeg simultaneously, I would do something like:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 \
    -c:v libx265 -c:a copy output1.mkv \
    -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output2.mkv
```

Is it possible to do something similar with ffprobe like:

```
ffprobe -i video.mp4 \
    -show_frames > 1.txt \
    -show_packets > 2.txt
```

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: Thanks. It was worth asking.